# Can two sources of information be combined to get a better prediction than given by either multiple regression or time series analysis?

Tags: time-series, multiple-regression, forecasting, predictive-models, repeated-measures

Suppose I have a data set, which I will call *Height-Weight-Age* featuring annual height and weight measurements of $N$ people from ages 10 to 30, where $N$ is relatively large, e.g. $N \approx 5000$. I will denote weight by $x$ and height by $y$ and use subscripts to indicate the age/time and superscripts to indicate the person's number in the dataset. So the *Height-Weight-Age* dataset is as follows:

Person 1: $\{(x_{10}^{(1)},y_{10}^{(1)},(x_{11}^{(1)},y_{11}^{(1)}), \dots,(x_{30}^{(1)},y_{30}^{(1)})\}$

Person 2: $\{(x_{10}^{(2)},y_{10}^{(2)},(x_{11}^{(2)},y_{11}^{(1)}), \dots,(x_{30}^{(2)},y_{30}^{(2)})\}$

...

...

Person N: $\{(x_{10}^{(N)},y_{10}^{(N)},(x_{11}^{(N)},y_{11}^{(N)}), \dots,(x_{30}^{(N)},y_{30}^{(N)})\}$

Now using this data I want to build a model such that I can predict a persons height given their age and weight.

I am aware that I could just take all the data and put it into a multiple regression model
$$
Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i + \beta_2 Z_i + \varepsilon_i,
$$ of height $Y_i$ vs weight $X_i$ and age $Z_i$. Once I've found the estimated coefficients $\hat \beta_0,\hat \beta_1, \hat \beta_2$ with ordinary least squares, I can make predictions of height given weight and age. For example, suppose a guy called John who is twenty-one years old comes along and tells me his weight. I can predict his height using
$$
\hat y_{21}^{(\text{John})} = \hat \beta_0 + \hat \beta_1 x_{21}^{(\text{John})} + \hat \beta_2 z_{21}^{(\text{John})}.
$$
Obviously $z_{21}^{(\text{John})} = 21$ but I write it like this as I am trying to keep the notation consistent. This is just standard multiple regression, which is what I am currently using.

But suppose John then says *"hang on a second, I recorded my weight every year from the age of ten up until now, here's the data"* and he gives me the following information: $\{x_{10}^{(\text{John})},x_{11}^{(\text{John})},\dots,x_{21}^{(\text{John})}\}$

So now instead of just having John's current age and weight I have a time series of age and weight data. I am still interested in predicting John's height but I now have two information sources:

- (1) General information: The *Height-Weight-Age* dataset for $N$ people which can be viewed as a set of $N$ time-series.
- (2) Personal information: A time series for John's weight from ages ten to twenty.

Now I could use the data in (1) to make a prediction $\hat y_{21}^{(\text{John})}$ of John's height using multiple regression as described earlier.

Alternatively, I could also make a prediction, this time I'll denote it $\overline y_{21}^{(\text{John})}$, of John's height using some time series analysis technique on the data in (2).

**My question now is can we somehow combine the two information sources (1) and (2) to make a better prediction of John's current height than those predictions given by $\hat y_{21}^{(\text{John})}$ and $\overline y_{21}^{(\text{John})}$ which each only used a single source of information?**

If so what type of model should I investigate? When I look up time series models, they are mainly focused on making a prediction of the current value $v_t$ of a time series based on $k$ previous values of the series $v_{t-1},v_{t-2},\dots,v_{t-k}$. But I don't have $k$ previous values of John's height, I only have $k$ previous values of his weight (which I know is correlated with height). So I is there an existing model or family of models relevant to making predictions for the case I am dealing with?

What general advice can you give me on my situation where I have both general information and person-specific information and I want to make a prediction?

Comment: You have *repeated measures* and should look into models for that!

Comment: In time series projections it is recommended by various authors you combine predictions because they improve results. This is I am sure not based on theory just experience. I don't know this applies to your analysis.